# Python, PySide6; JS not receiving data from QWebChannel

Tags: python, qt, python-3.10, pyside6, qtwebengine

I've seen many many answers about this question, but still cannot figure it  out.
I made two files, one - html with qrc definition + new QWebChannel, and second python file with Object and QWebEngineView.
JS script seems to not working. It doesn't binding channel object to local var.
I've tried many examples from many pages, looking native QT language or C++, I cannot figure it out.
QWebChannel definition and qt object are found.

Maybe something is not ok with PySide6? Please help me figure it out.

My code:

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let dataSource = null
        window.onload = function () {
            alert('before') //works
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
                    alert('inside') //not working
                    dataSource = channel.objects.backend;
                }
            );
            alert('after') //works
            alert(dataSource) //null
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

main.py

```
import sys, os

from PySide6.QtCore import Signal, QUrl, Slot, QObject
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import *
from PySide6.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel


class Backend(QObject):
    @Slot(result=int)
    def getValue(self):
        return 1

    @Slot(int)
    def printValue(self, val):
        print(val)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        backend = Backend()
        channel = QWebChannel()
        channel.registerObject("backend", backend)
        self.browser.page().setWebChannel(channel)

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "index.html")
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
        self.browser.load(url)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.resize(1200,900)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

***UPDATE:***

I extended view, added dev tool and jquery to check objects - that what I have:

[image: console log result on objects]

***UPDATE 2:***
I removed PySide6, installed PyQt5 and used example from here:
[How to receive data from python to js using QWebChannel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210400/how-to-receive-data-from-python-to-js-using-qwebchannel)

Everything works :/
I spend whole day to figure it out. I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: The issue with your original example is that you don't keep a reference to the channel, so it will be garbage-collected as soon as `__init__` returns. As [stated in the Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#setWebChannel),, the web-page does not take ownership of the channel, so you must either give it a parent (`channel = QWebChanne(self)`) or store it as an attribute (`self.channel = QWebChannel()`).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem recently, it turns out that the QWebChannel can not work inside QMainWindow. Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210400/how-to-receive-data-from-python-to-js-using-qwebchannel?noredirect=1&lq=1) I tried to learn how QWebChannel work with PySide6. And surely this following example work as expected:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var backend = null;
            window.onload = function()
            {
                new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
                    backend = channel.objects.backend;
                    var x = {a: "1000", b: ["Hello", "From", "JS"]}
                    backend.getRef(JSON.stringify(x), function(y) {
                        js_obj = JSON.parse(y);
                        js_obj["f"] = false;
                        backend.printRef(JSON.stringify(js_obj));
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

```py
import json

from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel


class Backend(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.Slot(str, result=str)
    def getRef(self, o):
        print("inside getRef", o)
        py_obj = json.loads(o)
        py_obj["c"] = ("Hello", "from", "Python")
        return json.dumps(py_obj)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def printRef(self, o):
        py_obj = json.loads(o)
        print("inside printRef", py_obj)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    backend = Backend()

    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()

    channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel()
    view.page().setWebChannel(channel)
    channel.registerObject("backend", backend)

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "index.html")
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
    view.load(url)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

However when I tried to bring the QWebChannel to QMainWindow it doesn't work:

```py
import json
import os
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, QUrl, QObject
from PySide6 import QtWebChannel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Backend(QObject):
    @Slot(str, result=str)
    def getRef(self, o):
        print("inside getRef", o)
        py_obj = json.loads(o)
        py_obj["c"] = ("Hello", "from", "Python")
        return json.dumps(py_obj)

    @Slot(str)
    def printRef(self, o):
        py_obj = json.loads(o)
        print("inside printRef", py_obj)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QWidget()

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        backend = Backend()
        channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel()
        self.browser.page().setWebChannel(channel)
        channel.registerObject("backend", backend)

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "index.html")
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
        self.browser.load(url)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec()
```

The solution that I found was by bringing out the QWebChannel from QMainWindow and it works the same as the first Python code above.

```py
import json
import os
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, QUrl, QObject
from PySide6 import QtWebChannel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Backend(QObject):
    @Slot(str, result=str)
    def getRef(self, o):
        print("inside getRef", o)
        py_obj = json.loads(o)
        py_obj["c"] = ("Hello", "from", "Python")
        return json.dumps(py_obj)

    @Slot(str)
    def printRef(self, o):
        py_obj = json.loads(o)
        print("inside printRef", py_obj)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QWidget()

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()

        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "index.html")
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)
        self.browser.load(url)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()

    backend = Backend()
    channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel()
    window.browser.page().setWebChannel(channel)
    channel.registerObject("backend", backend)
    
    window.show()

    app.exec()
```

I have no idea why it works that way, I hope someone else could give some insight about this.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @ekhumoro in the comment, adding the `self` argument inside the `QMainWindow` works as expected

```py
    backend = Backend(self)
    channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)
    view.page().setWebChannel(channel)
    channel.registerObject("backend", backend)
```

Comment: You must keep a reference to both `backend` and `channel`. In your second example, these will both be garbage-collected as soon as `__init__` returns. If you do `backend = Backend(self)` and `channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel(self)`, the second example will work as expected (because the parent window will keep them alive).

Comment: Whoa thank you, it is working inside the QMainWindow now!